# How do I place a video over top of an image on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a YouTube video that I am looking to place over top of an image on Wordpress. I'm sure it involves CSS and I don't know how to add CSS to Wordpress. I can add Raw HTML using the Visual Composer, but I don't think HTML would work here...

Everything I've tried so far only places the image over top of the video or underneath the video and that's only using the elements. Any ideas?

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if you don't supply the markup showing the situation you have? That's a requirement on SO if you want to ask questions here. A minimal example of the markup that shows the problem you are having. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a div that has the background set of image. Then, inside of the container, place your video.

Look at the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
.bgimg {
    background-image: url('../images/divbg.png');
}
</style>

...

<div class="bgimg">
    div with background
    [shortcode for video here]
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean? What type of element would that be?

Comment: please look at revised comment